# Why it's failed with message 'has a union with a field not allowed for this case' when I call VMware vCenter REST API to create disk

Tags: vmware, vsphere, vcenter

When I call VMware vCenter rest api to create a disk for vm, the api response with an error body:

Request:

**method**: POST
**Path**: rest/vcenter/vm/vm-xxxxx/hardware/disk
**Headers**: content-type:application/json accept:application/json vmware-api-session-id:xxxxxxxxx
**Body**: 
{

```
"spec": {

    "backing": {

        "type": ""

    },

    "ide": {

        "master": true,

        "primary": true

    },

    "new_vmdk": {

        "capacity": 1073741824,

        "name": "Hard disk 2"

    },

    "sata": {

        "bus": 0,

        "unit": 0

    },

    "scsi": {

        "bus": 0,

        "unit": 0

    },

    "type": "SCSI"

}
```

}

Response:
**Status**: 400
**Body**: 
{

```
"type": "com.vmware.vapi.std.errors.invalid_argument",

"value": {

    "messages": [

        {

            "args": [

                "com.vmware.vcenter.vm.hardware.disk.create_spec",

                "sata"

            ],

            "default_message": "Structure com.vmware.vcenter.vm.hardware.disk.create_spec has a union with a field not allowed for this case: sata",

            "id": "vapi.data.structure.union.extra"

        }

    ]

}
```

}

What's wrong with my calling to the api? I also tried type: "IDE", reporting "sata" too, or type: "SATA", reporting "scsi"

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Actually your issue is the Bus ID's

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got the root cause for this issue:

In the response, it reports "Structure com.vmware.vcenter.vm.hardware.disk.create_spec has a union with a field not allowed for this case"
The message are same when we assign "SCSI", "SATA", "IDE" to "type".
That is because definition of "com.vmware.vcenter.vm.hardware.disk.create_spec" has a union struct which union "SCSI", "SATA", "IDE".

So it's only allowed one of these 3 struct exists in the json body, for instance:

```
{
    "spec":{
        "ide":{
            "primary":true,
            "master":true
        },
        "type":"IDE",
        "new_vmdk":{
            "name":"Hard disk 4",
            "capacity":1073741824
        }
    }
}
```

Or:

```
{
    "spec":{
        "type":"SCSI",
        "new_vmdk":{
            "name":"Hard disk 4",
            "capacity":1073741824
        }
    }
}
```

(The 3 struct part are all optional, so only provide type and new_vmdk would create new disk. Even, type is also optional, vcenter would use guest default type.)